# JQuery - Custom slider - Restricting the slide when it reaches the end

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

I've written a custom slider using JQuery to show thumbnails of images. I've a outer div inside which the slider moves. But when the slides come to an end I don't want to slide further (both left and right). How can I do that?

Here is my code - You can save it as html and run it -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Content Slider</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });

        function left() {
            $('#inner').animate({
                'marginLeft': "-=200px"
            }, 1000, function () {
            });
        }

        function right() {
            if ($('#inner').css('marginLeft') != "0px" && $('#inner').css('marginLeft') != "auto") {
                $('#inner').animate({
                    'marginLeft': "+=200px"
                }, 1000, function () {
                });
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 200px; border: 3px solid #DADADA; overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;">
        <div id="inner" style="height: 190px; overflow: hidden;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="width: 100%; height: 190px;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: #DADADA">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table style="width: 800px">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <a href="Javascript:left();"><<</a>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <a href="Javascript:right();">>></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a check on the total number of images that is not initially shown. In your case it is = grand total - 4 (Shown when the page is initially loaded)- Call it X. Then use some sort of a counter to see that the margin left does not decrease by more than 200*X.

Code implementation:

```
var x=4; //current total is 8 (-4 gives x)
        function left() {
if( parseInt($('#inner').css('marginLeft'))>-x*200){ // 200 is the size of each image
            $('#inner').animate({
                'marginLeft': "-=200px"
            }, 1000, function () {
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: You might want to change the 200 to something like 205(considering the margin) and align the table a bit more to the left (to center it).

Comment: It wont help me because the last thumbnail may not appear fully. The outer width is not a multiple of thumbnail width. The outer width could be anything.

Comment: Alright that sort of sucks, but I did it with some fancy math... See it in action at http://fiddle.jshell.net/FJfyQ/3/ - the idea is to calculate the offset and correct it in the very last thumb's slide... P.S: I suggest that you make the outer an integral multiple of thmb width.(It looks better) :)